# New line within cell when exporting from Access to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Is there a way to export "new line" within cell properly when exporting from Access to Excel.

The data is entered in Access and new line in Access is showing OK.

However, when I export it to Excel it doesn't look well.

Tried to clean the text by removing all possible new line characters before inserting the value into Excel as follows (note that new line is required after the "comma" sign):

```
    FText = Replace(rs_Quotation!Text, vbCrLf, "")
    FText = Replace(rs_Quotation!Text, vbLf, "")
    FText = Replace(rs_Quotation!Text, vbNewLine, "")
    FText = Replace(rs_Quotation!Text, vbCr, "")
    FText = Replace(rs_Quotation!Text, ", ", "," & vbCr)
```

It seems good but when opened in Excel it adds some extra space above the text and some spaces between the lines:

[image: Example of blank text above cell contents]

However, after double clicking and exiting cell it gets to normal.

UPDATE: "AutoFit" method for EntireRow didn't produce any effect too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are going back to the source with every replace so only the last one is doing anything to your output. Try this:

```
FText = Replace(rs_Quotation!Text, vbCrLf, "")
FText = Replace(FText, vbLf, "")
FText = Replace(FText, vbNewLine, "")
FText = Replace(FText, vbCr, "")
FText = Replace(FText, ", ", "," & vbCr)
```

Add the following function to your code.

```
Public Function String2ASCIIString(ByVal strText As String) As String
    Dim i as integer
    Dim s as string

    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
        s = s & asc(Mid(strText, i, 1)) & ","
    Next
    String2ASCIIString = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
End Function
```

Add this next line just after the first block of code above.

```
Debug.Print String2ASCIIString(FText)
```

Run the code, press Ctrl+G, copy and paste the string of numbers as a comment.

Comment: That actually works for catching new line character and now the text doesn't have the blanks at the end of the line. It still has this wierd blank space above text though, even if the contents is one line only...

Comment: I updated my answer to assist with figuring out if there are any non-printable characters in your text that we should also replace.

Comment: ascii function gave an error in Access VBA. Thanks anyways for tips on error in logic. The issue with blank space resolved by moving the setting of column width BEFORE inserting values into cells...

Comment: I thought I tested that, sorry. ASCII should have been ASC. It should work now. Good to know you resolved it though; good job.